# Direct attestation with Webauthn in Safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, webauthn

I am creating a React app and am using Webauthn to use device biometrics for authentication.

My implementation works perfectly in Chrome however I get an alert saying 'The operation can't be completed' on Safari or any iOS device.

The error disappears when I set my attestation to 'none' however I need to use direct attestation for this app.

Has anyone experienced this issue before and managed to resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That's a limitation of WebAuthn in Safari unfortunately. Apple confirmed that when they launch passkeys officially in macOS Ventura and iOS 16 they won't support direct attestation either. Whether this means "direct" attestation will return no attestation, or error out instead as it currently does, is still TBD till they officially launch.

For now you'll have to decide to support use of Safari or not. You can either browser detect via user agent to request "none" attestation in Safari, or keep it "direct" and just not allow users to use Safari.